# Apps report screen reader in use, how do I find what app is reading my screen?

Tags: windows, display, accessibility

PowerShell, VisualStudio, and Discord all have told me I have a screen reader in use.  I do not knowingly have a screen reader in use.  It's possible I installed some app years ago that included that functionality, I don't know. It seems shady and makes me nervous, though.  I've looked at everything in task manager, psexplorer, autoruns, etc. and do not see anything obviously (to me) shady.  I've disabled/uninstalled a bunch of things, and even tried to use procmon to look for uses of the Windows screen reader DLLs, but see nothing.  But every time I open PowerShell it tells me a screen reader is in use.

Anyone have any further ideas as to how I can identify what is reading my screen?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, apparently an application could have in the distant past set a flag (not sure if in registry or where) indicating it was using the screen reader feature and that flag remains even after it exits/crashes.  There's a power shell script here that unsets the flag.  If the flag gets re-set after a reboot or something then obviously there is some app that is still running and using accessibility/screen reader functionality, but if it remains unset then presumably not.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11751#issuecomment-600120959